# PS-4 Autloading custom module

Tags: modules, composer

I have created a module in `modules/Core.php` which works great and I can reference it using `modules\Core::class`. But I want to re-organise my modules.

I'm not super familiar with PSR-4 loading but I have taken a look at a bunch of modules to try and copy the file structure and composer file.

Here's the file structure I want:

```
modules
  └── wrux
    └── Core
      ├── README.md
      ├── composer.json
      └── src
        └── Core.php
```

Here's my `modules/wrux/Core/composer.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "wrux/Core",
  "require": {
    "craftcms/cms": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "wrux\\Core\\": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

After I run `composer dump-autoload` I was hoping that I can use the `wrux\Core` namespace but it's not working. My module is only accessible from then `modules\wrux\Core\src` namespace.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 3):

1. I don't think you need to add any composer.json in your module folders
2. You have to update the project `composer.json` file only to let the craft know about custom module so that it can load on each boot.
3. Folder Structure might be like  (inside module folder at the root)

---

```
wruxmodule
└── src
    ├── controllers
    │   └── DefaultController.php
    ├── models
    │   └── WruxModuleModel.php
    ├── variables
    │   └── WruxModuleVariable.php
    └── WruxModule.php
```

1. Copy below line to `config/app.php`

---

```
 return [
    'modules' => [
        'wrux-module' => [
            'class' => \modules\wruxmodule\WruxModule::class,
        ],
    ],
    'bootstrap' => ['wrux-module'],
];
```

- Now update the project `composer.json` file

---

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "modules\\wruxmodule\\": "modules/wruxmodule/src/"
    }
},
```

- Finally run

---

```
composer dump-autoload ( at project root)
```